# finding element inside another element using id

Tags: jquery

I had google but did not find solution for my query.

What I want is I have following sample code

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <span id="sampleSpan"></span>
</div>

$("#mainDiv").find("#sampleSpan").css(\\doing some stuff);
```

So I want to access **sampleSpan** by id using it's parent container div **mainDiv**, I **only** want to access it by id. But I am not getting this. What is problem in this? and how to do this?

UPDATE:

As I know it can only access using **sampleSpan** but in my case I have problem is that, I am opening page in dialog box and which page open it also have same span **sampleSpan** so instead of getting opening **sampleSpan** it replace the first one.

I can not change the id because it has been used in too many codes, so I have only this option so I need solution for this only.

Comment: show the whole code please, because your query looks right. do you have a document ready wrapper? does the applied css take account for spans?

Comment: Ok, obvious questions based on your code. Is your jQuery in a `<script>` tag? Did you include jQuery? :)

Comment: You have an ID on the element...just use that?

Comment: Are you sure it's not finding the element?  Because the code shown is correct.  Also, you don't need the parent element in this case.  Since `id` values are unique, you can just access it directly: `$('#sampleSpan')`

Comment: that's an unnecessary redundancy, it needs to find 2 elements by ID whereas only a call to `$('#sampleSpan')` would suffice - there can't be 2 same IDs on page

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ucQLC/ check this here.

Comment: Guys I know that, however I should explain it first, please look for my update

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli yes your jsfiddle works but I got confused why my code is not working

Comment: Friends it is working fine, it was just another issue. thanks

Answer (score 3):

`id`s are unique.  Why not just reference `#sampleSpan` just like you referenced `#mainDiv`?

```
$("#sampleSpan").css(\\doing some stuff);
```

Comment: I know that, but I want to achieve according to my query, please look for the update.

Comment: because of parent logic

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you want to access and id only if its inside another id, so i dont find this problematic at all.

If `$("#mainDiv").find("#sampleSpan").css()` does not work, either your jquery does not get executed at all (does it?) or the css does get applied but does not show any change, because some css rules dont apply for inline elements as spans. MORE code please.

Make sure you load jQuery before you run your code and you have the document.ready() event function wrapping your code:

```
$(function() { /* your code */ });
```

More details, else, please.